# App Service Plan with high CPU without load

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We have an App Service Plan in Azure (PremiumV2: 1 Medium) with 14 App Services setup, but they are all stopped.

So without any load (that I know of), our CPU sometimes spikes to 100%. Is this normal? How can I find out what is causing the spikes? I'm guessing it isn't one of the App Services, since they are all stopped.

[image]

Comment: You could use KUDU And do a dump. Stopping the app doesn't delete the other resources contained in the App Service Plan.

Comment: @Rthomas529 Is it possible to get a dump for the entire App Service Plan, won't it be for just a single App Service if I use Kudu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, we click `stop` botton in the panel of Azure portal to stop an app service, but it only stop the main site you deployed under `wwwroot`, not the SCM site where Kudu & WebJob runs.

There is an offical document of Kudu wiki [Full stopping a Web App](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Full-stopping-a-Web-App) which may explain your current case. When you deployed some WebJobs running in your App Services, they will not be stoped by clicking the `stop` operation in Azure portal. And it seems to be some continous WebJob running which cause the CPU & Memory consuming.

If you want to stop all of them thoroughly, please follow the wiki above to know how to do. Hope it helps.